# Windows 10 - Overall volume extremely low

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

My notebook's sound volume is unnaturally quiet and I can sometimes barely understand a thing when watching some movies, despite my volume being turned up to 100% and everything in the sound mixer to the max, too. I've also applied volume normalization and it helped a bit, but not enought, so I decided to buy a bluetooth speaker to have a device that has its own volume independent from the PC hardware.

When I tested it with my phone and another PC, and it was as loud as I wanted it to be, so I connected it to the quiet notebook and to my surprise, the sound (again turned up to 100%) was *even* quieter than from its in-built speakers. Re-installed the Bluetooth driver and re-connected the speaker from scratch, but to no avail. The volume buttons on the speaker itself have no effect, they only seem to work with phones.

So how exactly is it possible the 100% on one PC and 100% on the other are not 100% for the speaker as you'd expect? What could be the issue here and how to solve it? Have never had something like this before.